# how to add values in array of object of all documents in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
 PostRequest:[
    {
        Description:{
            type:String,
        },
         Dates:{
           type:String,
       },
        Times:{
           type:String,
       }
    }
],
```

this is my schema and i want to add values in PostRequests for all documents.

Answer (score 0):

Query

- add multiple values(replace the `{"a": "1"}, {"c": "2"}` with the documents you want to add)
- to all documents of the collection (or specify a filter if you need one)
  (instead of multi:true, you can use the `updateMany` method)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6287ec08853f039c69b0f8e8)

```js
update({},
{"$push": {"PostRequest": {"$each": [{"a": "1"}, {"c": "2"}]}}},
{"multi": true})
```